# How to iterate over an array in C++ with mongodbcxx driver?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I couldn't find a simple answer on how to iterate over an array in c++ with mongodbcxx driver.

In the following document structure, I want to iterate over the field `arr` which is an array of integers.

```
{
  "_id": "01",
  "name": "Kong",
  "arr": [1,2,3] 
}
```

The following does not work.

```
    mongocxx::collection collection = db[kCollectionName];
    mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find();

    for(auto doc : cursor) {
       bsoncxx::document::element element = doc["arr"];
       bsoncxx::array::view arr = element.get_array().value;

       // A: The following code does not work. 
       for (bsoncxx::array::element i=arr.begin(); i!=arr.end(); i++) {
          std::cout << i.get_int32() << std::endl;
        }
    }

       // B: But this works
       for (bsoncxx::array::element i: arr) {
          std::cout << i.get_int32() << std::endl;
        }
```

Error when compiling with A.

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:461:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator!=(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:461:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from src/main.cpp:5:0:
include/mongodb_handler.h:87:64: note:   'bsoncxx::v_noabi::array::element' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
       for (bsoncxx::array::element i=arr2.begin(); i!=arr2.end(); i++) {
                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iosfwd:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/postypes.h:221:5: note: candidate: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator!=(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
     operator!=(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/postypes.h:221:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from src/main.cpp:5:0:
include/mongodb_handler.h:87:64: note:   'bsoncxx::v_noabi::array::element' is not derived from 'const std::fpos<_StateT>'
       for (bsoncxx::array::element i=arr2.begin(); i!=arr2.end(); i++) {
                                                                ^
include/mongodb_handler.h:87:68: error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]
       for (bsoncxx::array::element i=arr2.begin(); i!=arr2.end(); i++) {
                                                                   ~^~
include/mongodb_handler.h:93:3: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: _how_ does it not work? What exactly is the error? Could it be that `auto` isn't a reference?

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: `i` is an iterator, not an `element`, mate. Use `auto` or fully qualify the iterator type

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks. How can I use an `iterator` in this case? `.begin()` and `.end()` are specified in the [API reference](http://mongocxx.org/api/current/classbsoncxx_1_1array_1_1view.html). But if they are of type `element`, what is point of providing these?

Comment: The type is named `bsoncxx::array::view::const_iterator` by the looks of the docs; but honestly `auto` will be your best bet. Much clearer